# Is there any restriction to the number of testdata columns in a feature file - selenium java

Tags: java, maven, selenium, selenium-webdriver, cucumber

I am having a feature file with around 28 columns in the Examples section. When I run my code from cmd using mvn command, the scenario runs successfully, but the logs inside console are stuck at a point saying

```
1 Scenarios (passed)
8 Steps (passed)
0m51.054s

Running | Test Name | No| Yes| Neurology | abc name | data | test desc | Template | Yes| No | 20| 30 | Thursday | Yes | Yes | Yes | No | No | No | Yes | Yes | Yes | No | No |No | Yes | Yes
```

|

But as soon as I remove any of the columns, that is reduce it to 27 columns, it runs completely fine and the logs inside console end with a proper message:

```
1 Scenarios (1 passed)
8 Steps (8 passed)
0m43.964s

Running | Test Name | No| Yes| Neurology | abc name | data | test desc | Template | Yes| No | 20| 30 | Yes | Yes | Yes | No | No | No | Yes | Yes | Yes | No | No |No | Yes | Yes |
Tests run: 9, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 43.979 sec - in
Running | Test Name | No| Yes| Neurology | abc name | data | test desc | Template | Yes| No | 20| 30 | Yes | Yes | Yes | No | No | No | Yes | Yes | Yes | No | No |No | Yes | Yes |

Results :

Tests run: 9, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 53.205 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-06-05T23:05:32-04:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 14M/552M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Can anyone suggest why this behaviour is occuring?

Comment: which plugin are u using in the runner? Can u add the cucumberoptios of the runner?

Comment: @Grasshopper              
@CucumberOptions(
  plugin = {"pretty", "html:target/cucumber", "json:target/newFile.json"}
  ,features={".//src//test//resources//Features//NewFile.feature"} //name of feature file to be executed
  
  ,glue={"com.abc.stepDef"} // package in which the code for feature file statements is written
  )

public class Runner {